# Kusto Query to get the latest last date refresh value

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer

PFA, I am trying to fetch the latest date refresh record from the list of records but unable to get the last refresh date from the `daterefresh` column. Can you help how to get it the latest date refresh record

In the attachment I have given the example from the 3 records I need to get last refresh data Jan 3 2024 4:23PM record

Here is my query:

```
cluster('').database('').function
| where ServiceName == "My Service"
| where DateRefresh == <Need help here to filter the latest last daterefresh value>
| project DateKey,DateRefresh, ServiceOid, ServiceName, ServiceRing,SDL, SDLScore
```

Tried to get the single record to get the last refresh value but unable to get it. Need help to get the daterefresh value from the value

Answer (score 0):

you can use [the `arg_max()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction).

for example:

```
MyTable
| where ServiceName == "My Service"
| summarize arg_max(DateRefresh, DateKey, ServiceOid, ServiceName, ServiceRing, SDL, SDLScore)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work but I have explored and fixed it. below is the reference query?

MyTable
| where ServiceName == "My Service"
| top 1 by DateKey desc
| project DateKey,DateRefresh, ServiceOid, ServiceName, ServiceRing,SDL, SDLScore